# Is Accreditation a reserved word?

Tags: subsonic, reserved-words

Using Subsonic 2.2 latest SVN.

SQL Server 2008 table has a column called **Accreditation**

The Subsonic generated property for this column is named **AccreditationX**

Can anybody tell me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to guess it's the same name as your table...